# Unable to start server emulator - Exception in thread Thread-1 (run_http_server)

Tags: python, windows, lua, permissions, firewall

I'm a quite inexperienced Python user and I am attempting to use a Private Server emulator.
I installed the entire script like how I was told on its Github page (its called CockPY), but when I ran the script, I ran into an error.

```
I:\*certian gacha game*\CockPY-main>py -m cockpy
[BOOT] GAME SERVER STARTING ON LOCALHOST WITH PORT 22102
[BOOT] AUTH HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] PING HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] SCENE HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] DUNGEON HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] AVATAR HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] ENTITY HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] MAP_COMMANDS HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] CLOCK HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] GACHA HANDLER STARTED
[BOOT] LUAMULT HANDLER STARTED
Bottle v0.12.23 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:80/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Exception in thread Thread-1 (run_http_server):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "I:\*certain gacha game*\CockPY-main\sdk_server\app.py", line 262, in run_http_server
    app.run(host=host, port="80", debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\*my username*e\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 767, in run
    run(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3172, in run
    server.run(app)
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 2798, in run
    srv = make_server(self.host, self.port, app, server_cls, handler_cls)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 154, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 456, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\*my username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socketserver.py", line 472, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='I:\\*certain gacha game*\\CockPY-main\\game_server\\json\\excel\\MaterialExcelConfigData.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

This is not an issue with the actual program myself as I was unable to run into this error on one of my other computers.
I would like to know what causes the error "Exception in thread Thread-1" and "PermissionError: [WinError 10013"

my Python version is 3.11.4
my Windows version is Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.25393.1] (Windows 11 Zinc Insider Preview)
Here are all the script things I used for the server:
betterproto 2.0.0b5
bottle 0.12.23
Cython 0.29.32
loguru 0.6.0

I will not be able to access my other computer for a while so I can not gather much information but I do have a screenshot of the script not throwing out an error

Failed Tries:
I have moved my python folder to one of my external drives incase it was an issue with it being in the WindowsApps folder
I have tried reinstalling the main part of the script that makes it run (pyenet)
I disabled firewall and all of my Windows security
I have tried running the script from its .batch file (It immediately closes)

I think this is an issue with the permissions of the script maybe? Is there any way I can make the script have the full permissions and for it to run correctly?

(I'm not very experienced with python again, I don't know anything about writing scripts so I would love help with that if that is one of the issues)